# How change text width in table cell using autocad .net api C#?

Tags: c#, api, autocad, .net

I create Table using Autocad .net api C#.

```
 var table = new Table();
```

In single text(class DBText), change text width of the property - WidthFactor.

How change text width in table cell using autocad .net api C#?
 [[Image - different text width in cells table]](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120702/p726B8IO.jpg)

Comment: This was answered at: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/How-change-text-width-in-table-cell-using-autocad-net-api-C/td-p/3522862

Answer (score 0):

The text within an AutoCAD table can be formatted using the same technique as u would with MText. RTF

`{\W0.5;Text Width = 0.5}`

For a complete reference about [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)